# error saving the query string sent by ajax in a variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, url

I'm sending a variable value to an ajax page like this

```
var d = $('#sTree2').sortableListsToString();
$.post('myscript.php?url='+d);
```

the d value is

```
item_a=0&item_b=0&item_b1=item_b&item_b2=item_b&item_b3=item_b&item_b4=item_b&item_b5=
item_b&item_c=0&item_c1=item_c&item_c2=item_c&item_c3=item_c&item_c4=item_c&item_c5=item_c&
item_d=0&item_d1=item_d&item_d2=item_d&item_d3=item_d&item_d4=item_d&item_d5=item_d&
item_e=0&item_f=0
```

in the php file i save the value as usual

```
$url=$_REQUEST['url'];
echo $url;
```

but the result is

```
item_a=0
```

when I opened the network tab in the console and viewed the Preview of the ajax I found the same wrong value item_a=0 while the Header was correct containing the whole URL I mentioned above

Any suggestions?

[image: snapshot]

Comment: What you expect item_a value to be ?

Comment: I expect url=item_a=0&item_b=0&item_b1=item_b&item_b2=item_b ... etc and save the whole url in the php file in a variable but the sent data is item_a=0

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't encode your string properly. You're taking two separate url-encoded strings and slapping them together. The server has **NO** idea that you want the entire thing to be part of the `url` value, so it does what it should - decodes things into many separate key=value pairs.

You need to urlencode the `d`, e.g.

```
item_a=0&item_b=0&etc.. -> item_a=&amp;item_b=0&amp;etc...
```

Comment: Now the url is "u=item_a=0&amp;item_b=0&amp;item_b1=item_b&amp;item_b2=item_b&amp;item_b3=item_b&amp;item_b4=item_b&amp;item_b5=item_b&amp;item_c=0&amp;item_c1=item_c&amp;item_c2=item_c&amp;item_c3=item_c&amp;item_c4=item_c&amp;item_c5=item_c&amp;item_d=0&amp;item_d1=item_d&amp;item_d2=item_d&amp;item_d3=item_d&amp;item_d4=item_d&amp;item_d5=item_d&amp;item_e=0&amp;item_f=0" and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['url']` in php file, and send data via post like this:

```
$.post(url, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending data without a query string solved the problem

```
$.post('myscript.php?'+d);
```

then in php file

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url=end(explode("?",$url));
echo $url;
```